# How do i find extensions in VSCODE that are on lets say " blank lines" and also most popular

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do i find extensions in VSCODE that are on lets say  " blank lines" and also most popular

Comment: basically i want an extension that removes blank lines in VSCODE python and it should be also most popular.

Comment: Or you can find and replace all `\n\n` with `\n` using Find and Replace option.
And if that doesn't work replace `^(\s)*$\n` with nothing. That gotta remove every blank line.

Comment: dont think you understood the question.. I need to remove blank lines from the code in editor not in any output.

Comment: What I said is for editor only. Press `CTRL + H` which will bring up replace tool. There enter `^(\s)*$\n` in first input  box, keep second one empty. Make sure regex button is selected. And press replace all. It will remove all empty lines.

Comment: Maybe that works in some other editor but not VSCODE

Comment: It works in VS Code. Let me answer it with image.

Comment: @thisisjaymehta `()` not needed here,  `^\s*$\n` also works

Answer (score 1):

Press `CTRL + H`

Enter `^(\s)*$\n` in first input box

Make sure `.*` button is selected

Leave second input box empty

Click `Replace All` button

[image]

Comment here if any step is not working for you